# C#, Xamarin Forms: No Custom TextChangedEvent Raised on initialization

Tags: button, events, xamarin.forms, data-binding, behavior

I'm creating an Xamarin.Forms MVVM App (only using Android) which needs certain buttons to be outlined red, whenever their text property holds a specific value. (Purpose: alert the user to press the button and select a value, which will change the Button Text Property and therefore remove the red outline)

To achieve this I've create the following documents:

A custom button `CButton` that extents the default `Button`:

```xamarin
    public class CButton : Button
    {
        // this Hides the Default .Text-Property
        public string Text 
        {
            get => base.Text;
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                TextChangedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }

        }
        // The Raised Event
        protected virtual void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = TextChanged;
            handler(sender, e);
        }
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TextChanged;
    }
```

A custom behavior makes use of the raised `TextChangedEvent`

```xamarin
    public class ButtonValBehavior : Behavior<CButton>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(CButton bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }
        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string forbidden = "hh:mm|dd.mm.yyyy";
            if (forbidden.Contains((sender as CButton).Text.ToLower()))
            {
                //Do when Button Text = "hh:mm" || "dd.mm.yyyy"
                (sender as CButton).BorderColor = Color.Gray;
            }
            else
            {
                //Do whenever Button.Text is any other value
                (sender as CButton).BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#d10f32");
            }
        }
        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(CButton bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        }
    }
```

The relevant parts of the ViewModel look the following:

```xamarin
    public class VM_DIVI : VM_Base
    {
        public VM_DIVI(O_BasisProtokoll base)
        {
            Base = base;
        }

        private O_BasisProtokoll _base = null;
        public O_BasisProtokoll Base
        {
            get => _base;
            set
            {
                _base = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        Command _datePopCommand;
        public Command DatePopCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _datePopCommand ?? (_datePopCommand = new Command(param => ExecuteDatePopCommand(param)));
            }
        }
        void ExecuteDatePopCommand(object param)
        {
            //launch popup
            var p = new PP_DatePicker(param);
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(p);
        }
    }
```

The .xmal looks the following (`b` is the `xmlns` of the Namespace):

```xamarin
    <b:CButton x:Name="BTN_ED_Datum"
               Text="{Binding Base.ED_datum, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               Grid.Column="1"
               Command="{Binding DatePopCommand}" 
               CommandParameter="{x:Reference BTN_ED_Datum}">
        <b:CButton.Behaviors>
            <b:ButtonValBehavior/>
        </b:CButton.Behaviors>
    </b:CButton>
```

This solution works fine whenever the input is caused by user interaction. However, when a Value is assigned during the initialization of the Page no red outline is created, in fact the `TextChangedEvent` isn't raised. By using breakpoints I noticed that during initialization the `Text` Property of `CButton` is never set, eventhough it actually will be in the view.

Despite fiddling around with my solution I cannot make this work on initialization. I tried to work around this issue by outlining every button by default in their constructor, however this will outline every button red, even when their text value doesn't require them to be.

How can I achieve my initial goal?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to define a new property with the same name as in an inherited class, especially when the property you're trying to hide interacts with other properties. The [TextProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.button.textproperty?view=xamarin-forms) bindable property on the base `Button` class does not have any knowledge of your new `Text` property and this is likely the source of your inconsistent behavior. I recommend making use of the PropertyChanged event in your subclass and check for `e.PropertyName == nameof(Text)` instead.

Comment: As Andrew mentioned, try to modify the property `Text` to another name like `MyText` and use the new property in xaml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while but if I recall correctly what I ended up doing was:

- Changing the new `Text`-Property of my custom Button to `CText` and
- Making sure that I have `Mode=TwoWay` activated for any Element, that doesn't have it enabled by default. (Look up Binding modes on msdn for more)
- making `CText` a bindable property of `CButton`

My custom button now looks the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EORG_Anton.Model
{
    public class CButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CTextProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CText), 
            typeof(string), 
            typeof(CButton), 
            default(string), 
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: OnTextChanged);
        private static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CButton)bindable;
            var value = (string)newValue;
            control.CText = value;
        }
        public string CText
        {
            get => base.Text;
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                TextChangedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }

        }
        protected virtual void TextChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = TextChanged;
            handler(sender, e);
        }
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TextChanged;
    }
}
```